# How can we do Material-UI all useStyles into a single file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

we have `useStyles` in all pages. so need to add all the `useStyles` into a single file and need to remove in all pages.so how can we do it. Please help me on it.

Example below styles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    textAlign: "left",
  },

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
        minWidth: 150,
    },
    extendedIcon: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
```

Comment: Moving all styles in a single file won't be a wise decision. This will cause problems during maintaining your codebase in the future. If you still consider doing this, please describe more about your question and the reasons behind it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. please check with the updated query once.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, declaring all of your styles within a single page would be painful to maintain. But if you still want to do it, then you can rename the variables as per your page/component's name.

Suppose, if you have a page/component name `Home`, then you can declare your hook as `useHomeStyles` instead of `useStyles`. So, your "styles file" could look like -

```js
const useHomeStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        textAlign: "left",
    }
});

const useAboutStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
        minWidth: 150,
    },
    extendedIcon: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
});

// and other hooks of different pages...
```

Then in you `Home.jsx` file you can use it like,

```js
export default function Home(){
    const classes = useHomeStyles();

    return(
        <div className={classes.root}>Home Page</div>
    );
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bonnopc that it would be harder to maintain. But, you can also have all your styles in the one `useStyles`. You could have a file called `styles.js` as follows. Just have to make sure that you aren't using the same class name for different components. You might have a `root` class for your `Home` component and also one for `PageOne` component. When you combine them into the one `useStyles`, you'll have to rename one of the `root` class name to something else e.g. `rootPageOne`.

```
// styles.js

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        textAlign: "left",
    },
    formControl: {
        minWidth: 150,
    },
    extendedIcon: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    // insert other styles here
}))
```

Using it in `Home.js` will look like this:

```
// Home.js

import { useStyles } from "./styles.js"

export const Home = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>

        </div>
    )
}
```